# Django FormView and List of results

Tags: django, formview

Can i pass a model in FormView?

```
class TodoView(FormView):
    model = Branch
    queryset= Branch.objects.all()
    form_class = FormTodoAdd
    ...
```

How can i list the results of Branch in my Template?

```
{% for branch in object_list %} ## don't work
{% for branch in queryset %} ## don't work
{{ branch }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why would you use a form view, which is intended to handle a form, to display data instead of another generic view?

Answer (score 1):

Just because you define model attributes on a class doesn't mean that they get passed to the template context.

Your best bet is to pass the variables explicitly to the context, maybe with this:

```
class TodoView(FormView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        ctx['model'] = Branch

        return ctx
```

There may be other ways, but this is the simplest one I can think of.